# How to use custom decorator in angular injectable service

Tags: angular, decorator

i wan to use 'AOP' in my angular2 service ,for example,i want to request my server and get data,and i will check it return code ,i will show message by this return code,

for example :
here is my service:

```
@Injectable()
export class TemplatesService {

constructor(private http: HttpHelper) {

}

@show_message
public templates(search_params = {}): Observable<Array<Template>> {
    let params = new URLSearchParams()
    for (let key in search_params) {
        params.set(key, search_params[key])
    }
    return this.http.AUTH_HTTP_GET('api/templates.json?per=10000', params).map(data=> this.http.extractData(data).templates)
}
}
```

`HttpHelper` is my angular 2 http wrapper for some custom http header,body etc..

the show_message decorator:

```
export function  show_message(target:any,key:any,descriptor:any){
    console.log(target,key ,descriptor)
    const method = descriptor.value

    descriptor.value = (...args:any[]) => {

        let ret = method.apply(target, args);

        return ret;
    }

    console.log(method)

    return descriptor;
}
```

and here is the error:

```
    VM40526 TemplateIndexComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:5
 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'AUTH_HTTP_GET' of undefined
        at Object.TemplatesService.templates (eval at <anonymous> (app.cfb7cea….js:194), <anonymous>:31:25)
        at TemplatesService.descriptor.value [as templates] (eval at <anonymous> (app.cfb7cea….js:2349), <
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing wrong context.

According to the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#method-decorators)

> The expression for the method decorator will be called as a function
>   at runtime, with the following three arguments:

1) Either the constructor function of the class for a static member, or the prototype of the class for an instance member.

2) ..

So `target` is `TemplatesService.prototype` in your case but you should call method with current instance.

Try the following

```typescript
descriptor.value = function(...args:any[]) { // don't forget function 
  let ret = method.apply(this, args); // pass current context
```